# Handling dynamically added form controls with the same name

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP loop which outputs a series of identical form controls (they must be identical).

```
<input type=text value="Text Here" name="text_input">
<input type=text value="Text Here" name="text_input">
<input type=text value="Text Here" name="text_input">
<input type=text value="Text Here" name="text_input">
```

I have no problems styling with class names and whatnot in CSS, however on the back end, PHP can't get all of the data at once, because they are all using the same name.

How can I make it so that PHP can get and handle all of the fields? Do I need to configure something in PHP, or is there a nifty HTML trick that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add `[]` to the end of the name and it will be an array on the back end in php. Something like:

```
<input type=text value="Text Here" name="text_input[]">
<input type=text value="Text Here" name="text_input[]">
<input type=text value="Text Here" name="text_input[]">
<input type=text value="Text Here" name="text_input[]">
```

in php would be:

```
$_POST['text_input'][0] = ''; //whatever the first box had
$_POST['text_input'][1] = ''; //whatever the second box had
$_POST['text_input'][2] = ''; //whatever the third box had
$_POST['text_input'][3] = ''; //whatever the fourth box had
```

Other than that, why do the names "have to be identical"?

Comment: Bah, I knew that there was some HTML trick, They have to be identical because I don't want to deal with counters etc, also, I am also adding these in javascript after the page has finished loading, so....